# What countries is Google Play Books available?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-books

I wanted to install Google Play Books app from Play store. Unfortunately I got message, that

> This item cannot be installed in your device's country.

Can someone point me to list of countries, where this app is available?

As side note: if I travel to another country, can I install the app and then continue using it in my country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play Books is available in the US, UK, Canada and Australia. You can find this information on the [Google Play help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=play_faq&answer=2490014), and it has also been noted on the [@googlebooks Twitter account](http://twitter.com/#!/googlebooks/status/188365264675549185).

Comment: Google now have a single page that lists the international availabilty of all their Play store content, including Books, here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2843119

Answer (score 1):

If you download a book from the playstore in US, UK, Canada or Australia, then you go back to your country, you will still have the book, but won't be able to download anymore.

Comment: Welcome to the site! How do you know this? Is there some documentation or official statement you could link to, or is it from experience?